# NoReverseMatch with Django-survey?

Tags: django, django-templates

Ok, so this works in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^', survey_detail, {'survey_slug':'my-survey'},  name='survey-detail'),
```

I removed the above line and want to put the link in a template using `{% url %}`

I have the following line in urls.py:

```
url(r'^survey/', include('survey.urls'),
```

This is the line from the urls.py of the Survey app:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<survey_slug>[-\w]+)/$', survey_detail,   name='survey-detail'),
```

And this in my template:

```
{% url survey_detail 'my-survey' %}
```

I have also tried:

```
{% url survey_detail survey_slug='my-survey' %}
```

But I always get:

```
Reverse for 'survey_detail' with arguments '(u'my-survey',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

or

```
Reverse for 'survey_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'survey_slug': u'my-survey'}' not found.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The name is survey-detail and not survey_detail

Comment: oh, this seems to be the solution for your own question, sry for the above comment